# How to run a simple cpp file that requires QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I have QT 5.1.1 installed on my machine, but I'm having some troubles using it. I'm trying to run the following simple program that requires QT:

```
//Playing Video
#include "cv.h" 
#include "opencv2\objdetect\objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2\calib3d\calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2\nonfree\nonfree.hpp"
#include "highgui.h" 
#include <openbr\openbr_plugin.h>

using namespace cv;

static void printTemplate(const br::Template &t)
{
    const QPoint firstEye = t.file.get<QPoint>("Affine_0");
    const QPoint secondEye = t.file.get<QPoint>("Affine_1");
    printf("%s eyes: (%d, %d) (%d, %d)\n", qPrintable(t.file.fileName()), firstEye.x(), firstEye.y(), secondEye.x(), secondEye.y());
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    br::Context::initialize(argc, argv);
    // Retrieve classes for enrolling and comparing templates using the FaceRecognition algorithm
    QSharedPointer<br::Transform> transform = br::Transform::fromAlgorithm("FaceRecognition");
    QSharedPointer<br::Distance> distance = br::Distance::fromAlgorithm("FaceRecognition");
    // Initialize templates
    br::Template queryA("../data/MEDS/img/S354-01-t10_01.jpg");
    br::Template queryB("../data/MEDS/img/S382-08-t10_01.jpg");
    br::Template target("../data/MEDS/img/S354-02-t10_01.jpg");
    // Enroll templates
    queryA >> *transform;
    queryB >> *transform;
    target >> *transform;
    printTemplate(queryA);
    printTemplate(queryB);
    printTemplate(target);
    // Compare templates
    float comparisonA = distance->compare(target, queryA);
    float comparisonB = distance->compare(target, queryB);
    // Scores range from 0 to 1 and represent match probability
    printf("Genuine match score: %.3f\n", comparisonA);
    printf("Impostor match score: %.3f\n", comparisonB);
    br::Context::finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

It also requires OpenCV 2.4.6.1 and OpenBR, but that's not the problem.

All the definitions (variables and functions) in the above code that are related to QT are undefined. I've tried to find the relevant h files in QT folder and to include them, but that did not succeed since I couldn't fine qtcore.h (but a different file named qtcore with lot's of includes that I don't now how to use). I've tried to add QT "include" directory under "additional include directories" in the project properties but that didn't work either. I've also tried to add QT "lib" folder under "additional library directories" but that also did not work.

Basically, I tried everything I could think of. Can someone please explain how to I use those QT definitions? I'm really stuck and I could use any help given.

Thanks,
Gil.

Comment: Why you need Qt? As I can see in your code, the only types that you are using and belongs to Qt framework are QPoint and QSharedPointer. QSharedPointer alternative could be std::shared_ptr (c++11) or std::tr1::shared_ptr (c++98). QPoint could be easily implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. (Optional) Update to Qt 5.2.
2. Start Qt Creator.
3. Create a new Qt Widgets Application project. You can give the class/files random names, it doesn't matter. Uncheck the  "generate form" option, as you don't need any forms.
4. Remove all the files other than main.cpp from the project. You do this by right-clicking on them in the project tree on the left and choosing Remove File.
5. Copy-paste your code into main cpp. Make sure you completely replace main.cpp's contents, the default contents shouldn't be there anymore.
6. Add the opencv library to the project. Right-click on the project's root, select "Add Library", and go from there.
7. Re-run qmake by right-clicking on the project root and selecting "Run qmake".
8. Build and run the project by pressing Ctrl-R (Cmd-R on mac).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried doing what you suggested, but now QT doesn't recognize the "include" files. I added "INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opencv-2.4.6.1/build-msvc2012/include/opencv
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opencv-2.4.6.1/build-msvc2012/include/opencv2" to the pro file, but that didn't solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @GilLevi You only need a single include line that reads as follows: `INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opencv-2.4.6.1/build-msvc2012/include`

Comment: Thanks, @Kuba Ober, but I have such a line in my "pro" file and it still doesn't recognize the "include" files. Can you please help me to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Simply check where your opencv headers are, and add the full path to it in an `INCLUDEPATH += ` line. Something like `INCLUDEPATH += C:/foo/bar/opencv-2.4.6.1/include`.

Comment: Did you re-run qmake?

Comment: @GilLevi pauluss86 makes a very good point: every time you change the .pro file, you need to manually re-run qmake.

Comment: Yeah, cost me quite some time at first to discover that a 'clean + build' is not enough when changing .pro files. Also, I've seen cases where it appears the .pro file was parsed 'correctly', but had some error due to a typo. If the problem persists, please add the resulting output in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Qt uses a (non-standard) custom toolchain that has to run before the Qt-dependent code can be compiled. I've never tried using Qt outside of QtCreator, but if you really need Qt I'd suggest you use the QtCreator IDE; if you're not using it already of course. It's a very decent IDE, even for non-Qt projects.

Also, if you haven't done so already, make sure the Qt SDK is installed; the headers alone are not enough. QtCreator by itself is also not enough, you'll need the SDK. If you don't feel like doing so, my suggestion would be to look at Poco. It's not a 1:1 replacement for Qt, but a very mature framework nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks @pauluss86, can you please explain what exactly I need to do in order to run the code? 

I have QtCreator IDE installed, can you please guide me as to how exactly should I use it in my case (qmake etc.)?

Comment: @pauluss86 qmake is not any kind of a preprocessor. It's simply a tool that generates a makefile that then runs the proper tools to generate an executable. Those tools can include *several* code generators (not preprocessors!), such as moc, uic, qrc, ...

Comment: Good point, edited my answer! On a philosophical note: isn't changing the source files before they are given to the compiler always considered 'pre-processing'?

Comment: @pauluss86 Since no files are changed, there is no preprocessing involved. New source files are generated. And this is called code generation. And it is a technique that saves time and makes you productive, unless you consider writing moc output by hand a good use of your time.

Comment: @KubaOber, no I certainly don't consider writing moc output by hand a good approach... I'm not quite sure where I suggest otherwise? I use Qt quite regularly and am very happy with it, especially for GUI-related stuff! I'm just wondering about the definition of 'pre-processing' due to your earlier comment. Lastly, I'm not quite sure why my answer was downvoted? If there are any factual errors please let me know so I can edit my question.

Comment: @pauluss86 Sometimes an answer can have no factual errors at all yet be next to useless to the asker. The asker seemed to require step-by-step handholding. Also note that Qt SDK has been discontinued way before Qt 4.8 was released. There is no such thing as Qt SDK anymore. Qt 5 binary builds include Qt Creator, the headers, the tools, and the libraries - everything but a compiler. You can't but presume that someone so new as to be unable to compile a simple Qt-based project won't be building their own Qt and uses a binary build, with everything that it comes with. You chased red herrings.

Comment: @KubaOber Appreciate the response; still your last comment would've been  appreciated (to allow editing my answer) before downvoting it. Not much use of doing it now as it would replicate the steps in your answer. Anyhow, no hard feelings. Lastly, I like herrings and am principally against step-by-step guides on SO if there are well-documented tutorials\articles elsewhere that are easy to obtain. Qt is certainly well documented in my opinion.